A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<dynamic>'
I'm trying to use _showWindow function but I'm getting

A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type
'List'

error.
 void _addBook(BuildContext context) async {
    List<dynamic> result = await _showWindow(context, "Enter the book name") ?? [];

  }

_showWindow function:
Future<String?> _showWindow(BuildContext context, String title) {
    return showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          String result = "";
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(title),
            content: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              onChanged: (String inputText) {
                result = inputText;
              },
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, "");
                  },
                  child: Text("Cancel")),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context, result.trim());
                  },
                  child: Text("Approve"))
            ],
          );
        });
  }

How can I solve my problem? Thank you.

showDialog is not a list type, you will need to update your whole logic and code structure assuming what you want to do is keep a list of all the Books entered from the Dialog.

_showWindow returns String? not List<dynamic>.
Here's one way to handle this:
final _books = List<String>.empty(growable: true);
...
void _addBook(BuildContext context) async {
  final result = await _showWindow(context, "Enter the book name");
  if (result != null) {
    _books.add(result);
  }
}

}

**You need to return the List of Object you can't return the Widget in the Future<String?> U Need  To return List in _showWindow Please Modify the code **

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
